# How to create simple tree exmpdable/collapsible view using angularjs and specific data structure

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, treeview

I need tree view control it should just appear as below:

http://plnkr.co/edit/JAIyolmqPqO9KsynSiZp?p=preview

```
+Parent
     child
+Parent
     child
     child
     child
     child
+Parent
     child
     child
     child     
     child
     child
     child
     child
```

I just need simple tree as shown above, just need collapse- expand features and single level.

using angular 1.6 and bootstrap.

My collection data is - "List of Tasks" and each task has - "List Of Items"
how I could bind this and achieve above tree.

went though other links, but it seems complex with more features

please suggest any option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need a single level, you can use html table and 2 ng-repeats 1 for tasks and the other for child tasks. You can also also add a buttons to show/hide children.

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td><b>ID</b></td>
            <td><b>Task</b></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="task in ListOfTasks" ng-init="task.showChildren = false">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span class="label label-success">{{$index+1}}</span>
                <span>
                    <a class="label label-danger" ng-show="!post.showChildren" ng-click="task.showChildren = true">+</a>
                    <a class="label label-primary" ng-show="post.showChildren" ng-click="task.showChildren = false">-</a>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                {{task.TASK_NAME}}
            </td>
            <td class="table-actions"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-show="task.showChildren">
            <td>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-1">
                        <table class="table table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>ID</td>
                                    <td><b>Child Task</b></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr ng-repeat="childTasks in task.CHILD_TASKS">
                                    <td class="col-sm-1">
                                        <span class="label label-success">{{ $index + 1 }}</span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                       {{childTasks.CHILD_TASK_NAME}}
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="table-actions"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The table would look like [image]

Also if you don't wont to get all the data at start, you may getchildren on expand click

Comment: thanks for details. `-` for collapse is not appearing once it is expanded. And do you know, how to remove table lines and make it less width compact tree view.

Comment: I think you should write custom css for your table

Comment: or instead of table you can use rows and display items in col-md-* grid classes

Comment: thanks. It works, i have applied bootstrap column grid style to make compact and applied css to make some difference in table border.